# Is there a way to get the number of places after the decimal point in a java double?

Tags: java, groovy, floating-point, approximation

I'm working on a Java/Groovy program.  I have a double variable that holds a number that was typed in by a user.  What I really want to know is how many numbers the user typed to the right of the decimal place. Something like:

```
double num = 3.14
num.getPlaces() == 2
```

Of course, you can't do this with a double since that's using IEEE floating points and it's all an approximation.

Assuming that I can't get at the string the user typed, but only have access to the double the value has been stored in, is there a way I can scrub that double though a BigDecimal or somesuch to get the "real" number of decimal places?  (When the double gets displayed on the screen, it gets it right, so I assume there is a way to at least guess well?)

Comment: Footnote: as this is a mixed Java/Groovy codebase, any solutions using groovy-based sorcery will be more than welcome.

Comment: Do you want to know how many digits the user entered after the decimal, or how many digits will be printed after the decimal? Those are two totally different problems.

Comment: That the user entered. Good point.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No, you can't... because there are lots of different strings the user could have typed in which would all be parsed to the same value.

The "real" number is almost certain to have more decimal places than the user typed. For example, 3.14 is stored as exactly 3.140000000000000124344978758017532527446746826171875. I don't think you want to display *that* to the user.

To make the problem clearer, you can't tell from the double value whether the user actually entered:

```
3.14
3.140
3.140000
3.14000000000000012434
```

Those four strings will all give you the same value - which should make it obvious that you can't *possibly* get back to what the user typed in.

If at *all* possible, change the parsing code and use `BigDecimal` throughout.

Comment: Nitpick: If you're using 3.14 in your code, you should consider using `Math.PI` instead.

Comment: @R.Bemrose: Do you believe the number 3.14 never ever comes up anywhere without it actually meaning pi?

Comment: Guys 3.14 was just an example.  We're talking about arbitrary user entered doubles.

Comment: And, for the record, in the world where I am King (or, at least, Project Manager) all those doubles would become BigDecimals.  Sadly, I think that change might be received as being a little out of scope. ;)

Comment: 3.14 an PI - that reminds me of the famous Indiana Pi Bill: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indiana_Pi_Bill

Comment: Edit a year and change later: whoops!  I thought I had accepted this way back then!  Sorry, Jon.

Comment: @Electrons_Ahoy: LOL - I think this is one of the longest "post to acceptance" times I've had :)

Comment: @JonSkeet Well, it's still helpful all this time later, so... win?  Glad I can help try for another record. :)

Answer (score 3):

You are right there is something strange going on with doubles, what gets printed out is not the same as the contents of the variable.

for example:

```
groovy:000> "123.0001".toBigDecimal()
===> 123.0001
groovy:000> "123.0001".toDouble()
===> 123.0001
groovy:000> new BigDecimal("123.0001".toDouble())
===> 123.000100000000003319655661471188068389892578125
```

Notice the damage is done in the conversion of the string to a double, not when the double is passed into the BigDecimal. Feeding the double to the BigDecimal just provides an easy way to see what's actually in the double, because toString is lying to you.

As Jon Skeet points out, accuracy is not an option here. However, assuming the value printed out on the screen is the result of calling toString on the double, you should be able to get a bigDecimal that's no more wrong than the toString version of the double, like this:

```
groovy:000> d = "123.0001".toDouble()
===> 123.0001
groovy:000> d.toString()
===> 123.0001
groovy:000> new BigDecimal(d.toString())
===> 123.0001
```

So you don't need to involve the BigDecimal, really, you can just do something like

```
groovy:000> d = 123.0001
===> 123.0001
groovy:000> s = d.toString()
===> 123.0001
groovy:000> s.substring(s.indexOf('.')).length() - 1
===> 4
```

Sorry to invalidate your comment by editing.

BTW here's something close to Steve's answer, translated to groovy. (I took out the test for the decimal point not found because if you run this on a machine with locales messed up so it isn't using a period for the decimal point I'd rather it blow up than return 0)

```
def getPlaces(d) {
    s = d.toString()
    s.substring(s.indexOf(".")).length() - 1
}
```

Comment: Believe me, I wouldn't if I had the option.  But, you know, existing codebase and all that. I'm not even working on the module that collects the data, so I just get a double handed to me. :)

Comment: Man, at least mine isn't fiscal numbers, so the occasional rounding error is okay.

Comment: "Notice the damage is done in the conversion of the string to a double..." is an interesting turn of phrase.  For the casual reader, the 'damage' is that double is only an approximation.  A large majority of the numbers between min double and max double are not representable.  It does the best it can. :)  Double.toString() attempts to reapproximate what we mean since it is more likely that we meant 3.14 instead of 3.1400000000000001243... and so on.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can. At least if you don't mind that you sometimes get a wrong result.
We must assume that the user is lazy and has entered no more than ~12 significant decimal digits.

Then do the following:

- Create a BigDecimal with the given double in the constructor. That will convert the double in an exact decimal representation.
- Get only the fraction.
- Get BigDecimal.toString() and find three or more consecutive '0' or '9' digits.
- Cut off the fraction after those three digits. If the digits are nine, add a "1" at the
  end. After that remove all trailing zeroes.
- Count the remaining fractional digits

Warning: This may be a bit slow.

If you only want the number of significant bits in the double you can get them much faster and easier, but decimal->binary conversion unfortunately uses almost all bits.

Answer (score 1):

If you absolutely must take a double, and you don't mind having a little utility method to run it through, you could write something like this. You said you don't have access to the String value of what the user entered, but is there a reason why you can't convert it to a string and do something like this?

```
static int getPlaces(double num) {
    String numString = String.valueOf(num);

    return numString.indexOf(".0")==numString.length()-2?0:numString.length()-numString.indexOf(".")-1;
}
```

then, instead of your example

```
 num.getPlaces() == 2
```

You can do

```
 getplaces(num) == 2
```

I hope this helps..

Update, given your comment
`That the user entered. Good point.`

If the user entered what looks like an integer (say, 5) without a decimal point, and you're receiving it as a double, then what you're going to get is something other than what the user entered - for s/he will have entered 5, but you'll have received 5.0. You'd have no way of telling whether the user actually entered 5 or 5.0.

Comment: BTW, sorry that I don't have a groovy way of writing that method. I only know java..

Answer (score 0):

if you're stuck with a double, convert to a string and count the number of characters after the decimal point. I think there is some magic involved that displays numbers like 1.99999999998 as "2"

Answer (score 0):

so if it is a user entered value.  Accept the value as a String.  Then you can use string functions to find the position of the "." and then subtract that number from the length of the string to get the number your looking for.  Of course you'll want to trim() it, and verify it is in fact a number that was entered..

Comment: the question specifically mentions not having access to the string, only the double value.

Answer (score 0):

Convert to BigDecimal.
BigDecimal.scale() = number of places